# Removing linked file after updating to macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina, trash, x11

I updated to Catalina recently. When the update was done, I had a directory of recovered files on my hard drive. The only file recovered was a soft link to X11 (see below). I tried `rm X11` and `unlink X11` (with and without elevated privileges). Both times I receive "X11: Operation not permitted". This is annoying since this is now in my trash directory. Every time I empty the trash, I have to interact with a dialog telling me that macOS "needs" X11. It clearly doesn't since it's a symbolic link.

How can I remove the link?

```
Kyles-MacBook-Pro:.Trash kyle$ tree
.
└── Security
    └── usr
        └── X11 -> /opt/X11

3 directories, 0 files
Kyles-MacBook-Pro:.Trash kyle$ ls -l Security/usr/X11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 Dec 28  2017 Security/usr/X11 -> /opt/X11
```